# Angular/javascript: Read values from a GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

A simple question, I'm sure ...

I am trying to create a  and load it with values from my MongoDB.
From colsole.log I am sure that the query is being executed as expected but the  is being populated with ...

```
function (a){Qa(a,"fn");h.then(function(b){a(b.data,b.status,b.headers,f)}); return h}
function (a){Qa(a,"fn");h.then(null,function(b){a(b.data,b.status,b.headers,f)}); return h}
```

The select angular/html

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="opt as opt for opt in months" ng-init="selected='March'"></select>
```

And the Controller

```
$scope.months = $http.get("/utility/monthList");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $http.get("/utility/monthList").then(function (response) {$scope.months = response.data });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plnkr which illustrate your solution, I hope this helps you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/50q9N6TmU7ubouMcgenW?p=preview

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="opt as opt.FirstName for opt in months" ng-init="selected='March'"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks Deepanjan.
The plinkr demo was very useful

Answer (score 3):

Since [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).get returns a promise you need to update the response when the promise is resolved:

```
$http.get("/utility/monthList").then(function(res){ $scope.months = res.data; });
```

Read more about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).